# How to check if a model has a certain column/attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a method that needs to loop through a hash and check if each key exists in a model's table, otherwise it will delete the key/value.

For example:

```rb
number_hash = { :one => "one", :two => "two" }
```

and the Number table only has a :one column so :two will be deleted.

How do I check if a model has an attribute or not?

Answer (score 246, accepted):

**For a class**

Use `Class.column_names.include? attr_name` where `attr_name` is the string name of your attribute.

In this case: `Number.column_names.include? 'one'`

**For an instance**

Use `record.has_attribute?(:attr_name)` or `record.has_attribute?('attr_name')` (Rails 3.2+) or `record.attributes.has_key? attr_name`.

In this case: `number.has_attribute?(:one)` or `number.has_attribute?('one')` or `number.attributes.has_key? 'one'`

Comment: For bonus points use `Hash#select`: `number_hash.select { |key, value| Number.column_names.include? key }`

Comment: In Rails 3.2+, use `number.has_attribute?` which accepts a Symbol or a String

Comment: I believe if an object delegates a method to another object, this method will erroneously suggest the column exists. I was checking my models for ones that had a `user`, but had to instead look for `user_id` since some models delegated user.

Comment: `Hash#has_key?` is deprecated in favor of `Hash#key?`

Comment: How about using [attribute_method?](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/ClassMethods.html#method-i-attribute_method-3F) for a class:
`Number.attribute_method? 'one'`

Comment: Beware of `has_attribute?`. If you pass an explicit select, e.g. `Model.select(:id, 'SUM(...) AS mysum)...` then `result.has_attribute?(mysum)` will return true. Attempting to `assign_attributes` or similar operations will then fail because the column doesn't exist.

Comment: You can simply add `record.try(:column_name)` it will return then nil if column not exists

Answer (score 15):

If you need to check for aliases as well, you can use `Number.method_defined? attr_name` or `number.class.method_defined? attr_name`.

I had to do this for a Mongoid object that had aliased fields.

Comment: I found `ModelName.attribute_method? :attr_name` was what worked in my instance

Answer (score 10):

In your instance object, you could use also `defined? instance.attribute` or `instance.respond_to? :attribute`.
These are more generic solution to check a model attribute or any method as well.

Comment: Please keep in mind: `instance.respond_to?(:attribute) == false ; instance.attribute ; instance.respond_to?(:attribute) == true`

Answer (score 5):

if very simplified

**for Model** columns < attributes < methods

**for record** columns = attributes < methods

**Model.columns <> Model.record.columns/attributes**

**column**

Checking the existence of a column for a model
`Foo.column_names.include? 'column_name'`

Does the column exist for the record?
`foo.has_attribute?('column_name')`

**attribute**

Checking the existence of a attribute for a model
`Foo.attribute_method?(:attribute_name)`

Does the attribute exist for the record?
`foo.has_attribute?(:attribute_name)`

**method**

Checking the existence of a method for a class
`Foo.method_defined?(:method_name)`

Does the method exist for the instance?
`foo.respond_to?(:method_name)`