# check existence of particular column in rails array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays

I want to know if there is any array method to check existence of particular column in model. I have combined query results from two tables into an array. I need to check exitence of those tables column name inj that array.

Comment: Please be a bit more elaborate. Your question is not clear enough.

Comment: Duplicate of [How to check if a model has a certain column/attribute?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710004/how-to-check-if-a-model-has-a-certain-column-attribute) that has better question and answers.

Answer (score 3):

```
Model.columns.map(&:name).include?("id")
# => true
Model.columns.map(&:name).include?("not_available_column")
# => false
```

Answer (score 1):

Another, perhaps cleaner way of doing this is: Foo.column_names.include?("bar")

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can check if a model instance is of a particular class, eg `obj.is_a?(Person)`.

To see which columns a certain model has, you do it at class level: `obj.class.columns.collect { |c| c.name }`.

Comment: even shorter: obj.class.columns.map(&:name)

Answer (score 0):

You could use this also:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.column_exists?(:users, :id)
```

[Api Dock - column_exists?](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/column_exists%3F)