# how to find the table column name is already exist or not in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite

Example:

i am having old table columns format (id , name ,city) but now we have modified table columns like (id , name ,city , pin)

i want to check whether the "pin" column present in the table or not in ruby on rails

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check if a model has a certain column/attribute?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710004/how-to-check-if-a-model-has-a-certain-column-attribute)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails 2.3.x:

```
Model.columns.map(&:name).include?('pin')
```

Rails 3.x:

```
Model.column_exists?(:pin)
```

Comment: `column_exists?` is not a method available from a `Model`.

Comment: Model.connection.column_exists?(table_name, column_name) [docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/column_exists%3F)

Comment: If you want to use column_exists you have to do this. ActiveRecord::Base.connection.column_exists?(:table_name, :pin)

Answer (score 1):

you can do this to get an array of all column names from a table as symbols :

```
YourModel.arel_table.columns.map( &:name )
```

to check if `pin` column is present :

```
YourModel.arel_table.columns.map( &:name ).include?( :pin )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [column_exists?](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/column_exists?) to check the existence of a column for Rails 3.0 and later.