# Is there any way to check that has_many association exists in Rails 3.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

For example there are some models

```
class Model_1 < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :images, :as => :imageable
end

class Model_2 < ActiveRecord::Base
   # doesn't have has_many association
end
...
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :imageable, :polymorphic => true
end
```

How can I check that model has has_many association? Something like this

```
class ActiveRecord::Base
    def self.has_many_association_exists?(:association)
        ...
    end
end
```

And it can be used so

```
Model_1.has_many_association_exists?(:images) # true
Model_2.has_many_association_exists?(:images) # false
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 24, accepted):

What about [`reflect_on_association`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Reflection/ClassMethods.html#method-i-reflect_on_association)?

```
Model_1.reflect_on_association(:images)
```

Or [`reflect_on_all_associations`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Reflection/ClassMethods.html#method-i-reflect_on_all_associations):

```
associations = Model_1.reflect_on_all_associations(:has_many)
associations.any? { |a| a.name == :images }
```

Answer (score 4):

I found the following to be the simple way to achieve the desired result:

```
ModelName.method_defined?(:method_name)
```

Example:

```
Model_1.method_defined?(:images) # true
Model_2.method_defined?(:images) # false
```

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18066069/936494

Comment: This aproach is not fully compliant. Try it with :destroy, for example. Is not a relation but te object has this method.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably use respond_to?

```
class ActiveRecord::Base
    def self.has_many_association_exists?(related)
        self.class.associations.respond_to?(related)
    end
end
```

Comment: I'd probably go with KARASZI István's answer!

Answer (score 0):

You could just have a method that tries to access a Model_1 object images inside an exception block like (roughly) :

```
begin
  model1_obj.images
rescue
  puts 'No association between model_1 and images'
end
```

Inside rescue, you can just return false if you like.

Comment: That could be a method, or attribute, or anything. Not an association. But yes, duck typing :)